# Create file structure from strings

Tags: java, servlets, bitbucket-api

I am trying to create a BitBucket plugin to get the repository structure and print it out in a structured format. The plugin creates a button on the repo page and when clicked it connects with a servlet to produce an output, however I cannot get my formatting code to work.

E.g
Instead of:

- Folder 1
- File 1
- File 2

I want it to indent children:

- Folder 1

  - File 1
  - File 2

I currently have a JS file which controls the button and makes an ajax call to a Java file, and also passes the servlet URL including the parameters for the repo (Project, Repo).
In my Java file I have a doGet which gets the repo from the parameters and uses a custom contentTreeCallback() to get the files within the repo in order to print them out, using callback.getFiles(). Within this same Java file, I have defined a node class which creates a linked hash map which takes each file, splits it into components, and with a recursive loop appends children to nested lists in order to create the file structure. This should work, however my custom contentTreeCallback() gets a string rather than the file array it needs to return. I cannot figure out what changes I need to make to get this to work. I'm guessing I either adjust the callback to get the files or I move the node class functionality into the callback class. I would prefer the second option since this class already splits the string, it seems a bit redundant to do it twice.

The servlet java class:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {

        // Get values from the URL 
        projectName= req.getParameter("project");
        repoName = req.getParameter("repository"); 

        repo = repositoryService.getBySlug(projectName, repoName);

        // ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        MyContentTreeCallback callback = new MyContentTreeCallback();
        PageRequestImpl pr = new PageRequestImpl(0, 1000);

        // Get information from the defined location, store in ByteArrayOutputStream
        contentService.streamDirectory(repo, "Master", "", true, callback, pr);

        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        resp.getWriter().print("<html><body><p>Repository: " + repo.getName() + "</p>");

        Node root = new Node(null);

        for(int i = 0; i < callback.getFiles().size(); i++) {
            root.add(callback.getFiles().get(i));
        }

        root.writeTo(resp.getWriter());
        resp.getWriter().print("</body></html>");

    }

    static final class Node {
        final String name;
        final Map<String, Node> children = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        Node(String name) { 
            this.name = name; 
        }

        void add(File file) {
            Node n = this;
            for(String component: file.getPath().getComponents())
                n = n.children.computeIfAbsent(component, Node::new);
        }
        void writeTo(Appendable w) throws IOException {
            if(name != null) w.append("<li><a href='/'>").append(name).append("</a></li>\n");
            if(!children.isEmpty()) {
                w.append("<ul>\n");
                for(Node ch: children.values()) ch.writeTo(w);
                w.append("</ul>\n");
            }
        }
    }
```

And the custom callback class:

```
public class MyContentTreeCallback extends AbstractContentTreeCallback {
    
    ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
    
    ContentTreeSummary fileSummary;
    public MyContentTreeCallback() {

    }
    
    @Override
    public void onEnd(@Nonnull ContentTreeSummary summary) {

        fileSummary = summary;
    }
    
  @Override
    public void onStart(@Nonnull ContentTreeContext context) {
      System.out.print("On start");
       
    }
    
  @Override
  public boolean onTreeNode(@Nonnull ContentTreeNode node) {

      String filePath = "";
      if (node.getPath().getComponents().length>1) { 
          for(int i=0;i<node.getPath().getComponents().length;i++) {
              filePath+=node.getPath().getComponents()[i]+"/";
              //filePath=filePath.substring(0,filePath.length() - 1) 
          } 
      } 
      else {

          filePath+=node.getPath().getName(); 
      }

      String lastChar = String.valueOf(filePath.charAt(filePath.length() - 1));
      if(lastChar.equals("/")){ filePath=filePath.substring(0,filePath.length() -
              1); }

      files.add(filePath);

      return true;
      
    }
  
    public ArrayList<File> getFiles(){
        return files;
    }
    
}
```

files.add(filePath); Is where the issue is in the callback class.

I'm sure it's simpler than I am making it out to be... Thanks for any help you can give

Comment: (I removed the JavaScript tag, since it's only mentioned)

Comment: You are trying to add a `String` to an `ArrayList<File>`. I don’t understand why you are trying all that processing in `onTreeNode`, instead of just doing `files.add(node.getPath());`

Comment: @Holger I have tried that but getPath() returns a path so I cannot add it to ArrayList<File>

Comment: Well, in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72741059/best-way-to-sort-strings-of-filepaths-into-a-directory-structure?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment128484766_72741059) you created the impression to have instances of `File` which is a subclass of `ContentTreeNode`. The solution, however, does not depend on `File` at all. So just replace all occurrences of `File` in this code by `ContentTreeNode` and change `onTreeNode` to `files.add(node);` You could even get rid of the `ArrayList` by creating the root `Node` first and let the callback invoke `add` directly on it.

Comment: Omg of course, I just totally missed the fact that file is not necessary. Yep with changing the array to contain ContentTreeNodes it works how it should now. thanks for all of the help man

Comment: @Holger sorry to keep coming back to this, but with this approach is there any way to create a path so I can link to each location within the tree? I have the main address, I would just need to append each level in the list followed by the file name, but I cant see how this would work with the way writeTo calls back to itself

Comment: I’m afraid I didn’t understand what you want to change.